# SQL Server results into a single string with counter

Tags: sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
 Product_Id      Description
 ---------------------------
  BX01              Desc 1
  BxX1              Desc 2
  Dss3              Desc 3
  HHXY              Desc 4
```

I want the result to be exactly:

```
1 - BX01, 2 - BxX1, 3 - Dss3, 4 - HHXY
```

I have this query:

```
DECLARE @ProID VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @ProID = COALESCE(@ProID + ', - ', '') + Product_Id FROM TABLE      
SELECT @ProID
```

but the return values is only :

```
BX01,- BxX1,- Dss3,- HHXY
```

The counting is missing.

How to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the numbers are the row numbers, you should be using `ROW_NUMBER()` ([more info](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)):

```
DECLARE @tmp TABLE (ID varchar(300), [Desc] varchar(300))

INSERT INTO @tmp (ID, [Desc])
SELECT 'BX01', 'Desc 1'
UNION
SELECT 'BxX1', 'Desc 2'
UNION
SELECT 'Dss3', 'Desc 3'
UNION
SELECT 'HHXY', 'Desc 4'

DECLARE @ProID VARCHAR(8000)  
SELECT @ProID = COALESCE(@ProID + ', ', '') + CAST(t.row AS varchar(20))+ ' - ' + t.ID
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS row, ID
    FROM @tmp) AS t

SELECT @ProID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this using row_nu,mber function

```
SELECT CAST(row_number AS VARCHAR(5)) +' - '+ Product_Id +', '
from
  (select Product_Id, ROW_NUMBER()OVER(order by Product_Id) as row_number
   FROM TABLE      ) as derived_tbl
FOR XML PATH('')
```